# Stata Duplicates within a 5 minute trange

Tags: duplicates, stata

For the following dataset example:

```
 11-12-2014 21:59
 11-12-2014 21:59
 11-12-2014 22:00
 11-12-2014 22:06
```

I need to regard observations that are less than five minutes apart as duplicates and use them in a "bysort" command afterwards. Does anyone know how I can define duplicates to be observations that are <5 minutes apart?

Comment: Key to answering that question is knowing how you want to treat observations at 21:00, 21:04, and 21:08. Each is 4 minutes from the adjacent observation, but the first and third are separated by 8 minutes.

Comment: @William, briliant question. I would probably agree to most solutions. Ideally five minutes from the smallest value, 21:00 would be the original, 21:04 the duplicate and 21:08 would be a new original.

Comment: Another difficulty is that dropping duplicates on time may be arbitrary with respect to other variables. Your first and second observations have identical times, but do they have identical values on all other variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer, since for clarity I used simple numbers rather than Stata time values. But it shows the fundamental idea.

```
clear
input float x
 1
 3
 9
13
17
end
generate run = 0
replace run = x in 1
replace run = cond(x<=run[_n-1]+5,run[_n-1],x) if _n>1
```

which gives the following result, showing that the variable `run` identifies sets of "duplicate" observations by your criterion.

```
. list

     +----------+
     |  x   run |
     |----------|
  1. |  1     1 |
  2. |  3     1 |
  3. |  9     9 |
  4. | 13     9 |
  5. | 17    17 |
     +----------+
```

Comment: See also `panelthin` on SSC, except that it assumes `tsset` data and cannot cope with pure duplicates.